# Python built open node graph?

Tags: python, model, workflow

after hunting through stackoverflow, I still can't find quite what I'm looking for.

**Question:**
I am looking to use (or create if this doesn't exist) an open source node graph, as a node-based approach to using Python code.

**Clarification**
*Let me explain the concept of what I mean by "Node graph".*
A node graph is a place to create "nodes", represented by little boxes with connections. The user can move select them, move them around, make and break connections based on appropriate data types.

**Example**
For example- and I think to myself, "surely this has been done before," but I'd like to write nodes in python script that load data, process that data in some way, etc. 
For example, I want to write a python node that loads time based data from a file OR a real time source, then another node that processes it, then another node that maybe visualizes it, or writes out a custom format to file. 
**Background** I come from a background in 3D animation where we use the software packages Maya and Nuke to process data in this way using node-based workflow- however the architectures are very high-level and specialized. What I want to do is reduce this idea of workflow to a very mid-low level. All I want is a node graph with custom python nodes.

**So far I have tried:**

- Nodebox 3 - this is a high level software built on Java and compiled code. Seems to be too high level for me (with a fully functional gui) and too java based
- Nodebox Windows - a nifty OpenGL derived library, but too low level, would have to build an interactive node graph from scratch
- Coral - an interesting idea but too specialized in 3D I think, for doing generic data processing as I'd like. Perhaps I could modify it, but I'm afraid the dying community might hold me back.

appreciate any other suggestions you guys may have.

** EDIT **
StackOverflow won't let me post a screenshot example.. annoying.
A visual programming language- this general idea is what I'm looking for! But what I would prefer is the ability to write functions in Python and then graph them visually like those languages.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of something like this? I feel that would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but highly specialized. You're likely going to need to build it yourself from scratch.

Comment: Are you referring to a Visual programming language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language ?

Comment: Why not stay within Nuke itself, and create custom Nodes (gizmos) there? You get the full power of Python 2.x in any Custom Nuke Node.

Comment: Because Nuke is purely for image processing, (and commercially licensed). An open source python based graph would be great for myself and for others to model custom applications from.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/flowchart/index.html)

It has a node-graph among a lot of other visualization Widgets. It's called flowchart and lets you create and connect nodes. Each of these contains a python function to modify its input data.

As the name implies it relies on PyQt/PySide.